# All subprocesses are Bash (!),

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh, exec

I was trying to use GDB, and found that whenever it attempted to spawn the program I was debugging, Bash was spawned instead (GDB would say `starting myProg...`, and then Bash would appear. When I killed Bash, I'd be back in GDB, which would tell me Bash's exit status). At first I thought it was a bizarre problem with GDB, but then I discovered that trying to spawn a process from Vim also just spawned Bash.

Through a weird flash of inspiration I connected this problem with the fact that my default shell is Tcsh, and as I'm not allowed to change it, I simply set my `.tcshrc` to contain `exec bash`. When I changed this to `bash` or just used Tcsh the problem disappeared.

I have absolutely no insight into how the Tcsh thing leads to my problem. Could anyone provide any?

---

As an aside, I was able to get a temporary fix running GDB by `PATH="" /usr/bin/gdb` instead of just `gdb`. It spat out `bash: command not found`, and then proceeded to spawn the program I wanted to debug.

Comment: Cheers guys,

I've been using Linux for 3 or 4 years now and it never before occurred to me that processes got spawned via a shell like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is clearly that `gdb` uses a shell to spawn processes.

Vim does it for sure (`help !`)

```
:!{cmd}         Execute {cmd} with the shell.
```

So when we say `:!ls -l` Vim will execute in fact

```
$ SHELL -c 'ls -l'
```

I think (given I understood your *hackish* setup correctly) you can fix it easily by executing `exec bash -l` instead of `exec bash`.

Reason being, `exec bash` (not being login shell) will not change the `SHELL` environment variable which is later on used by `gdb` and `vim` and points to your login shell (`tcsh`). They should use your shell of choice (`bash`) directly.

**NOTE:** You might want to think what happens when you will be running some program written in `tcsh`. It will probably not behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation of the other answers are fine.

As a solution I would set `export SHELL=bash` many commands like gdb or screen use this variable to determine what kind of shell to use to spawn commands.

Therefore bash is used directly to spawn your command instead of tcsh which is configured to only start bash.

---

You can maybe improve your setup by using an ssh-key to log into your server and add a forced command to your key in the authorized_keys file.

This way you can start directly in bash but do not break any tcsh scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In your .tcshrc file you can wrap your `exec bash` like this:

```
if ($?prompt) then
    exec /path/to/bash
endif
```

`$?prompt` will be false for non-interactive shells so bash is only used when you have an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what is happening is when you execute a program from inside GDB, it is launching a subshell to run that program and thus sources that rc file.

the exec man page says that "The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image"

I think that what is happening is when you call exec in the rc file it replaces whatever you were going to run with bash and then when you exit, you return to GDB with the bash exit code.  If you want to use exec with bash and get your program to run, you probably need to figure out where tcsh's equivalent of Bash's argv is storing the program call to whatever you wanted to run and pass that to bash.

You could also get fancy in that rc file and inspect the argv and determine if you are trying to run a program, or just get a login shell and do different behavior based on that.